# Give me an advice for how to set a page title in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, title

I have a number of Views in my site that have a different logics. I want to change the page title depending on the View that is loaded. The way I am doing it right now is by JavaScript that finds an element in the loaded page and then : `document.title = $("#current-loaded-element")[0].innerHTML`

The page title is always loaded in the current page but it also comes with the object passed to the current View. Which one is better : setting it by javascript or by **@Model.PropertyName**

Comment: which version of mvc framework are using?

Comment: The version that I am using is MVC 4

Comment: @ViewBag.Title would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't just leave default way to set title in ASP.NET MVC through `ViewBag.Title`?

I think it would be better way to do it because your site will work for clients that turned off javascript and for search engine robots the same way.

Just have a look at default ASP.NET project and you will see on Layout.cshtml:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Then for changing it you need just assign needed value to ViewBag.Title on specific page, like this:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "This is home page";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the ViewBag for this as follows:

Add this to your _layout.cshtml

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Then add this to your view:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}
```